# How to merge lines that start with the same items in a text file

Tags: regex, replace, grep, textwrangler

I have a text file containing some thousand lines as follows:

**File:**

```
abc: bla1 bla1 bla1... 
cde: bla bla bla... 
ghk: bla1 bla1 bla1... 
lmn: bla bla bla...
abc: bla2 bla2 bla2... 
bcd: bla bla bla... 
ghk: bla2 bla2 bla2... 
xyz: bla bla bla...
```

I want to merge all the lines that start with the same items (as `1 and 5, 3 and 7`) so that I have  a new text file like this:

**New File:**

```
abc: bla1 bla1 bla1... * abc: bla2 bla2 bla2... 
cde: bla bla bla... 
ghk: bla1 bla1 bla1... * ghk: bla2 bla2 bla2...
lmn: bla bla bla...
bcd: bla bla bla...   
xyz: bla bla bla...
```

I wonder if this is possible to be solved using `regex` and/or `grep`, and if yes then how can I solve it?

I'm quite familiar with `grep` because I'm on TextWrangler, but also OK with other text editors.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is an elegant solution for this. Try a Perl approach. First pass, populate a hash with key's being the start items where the hash value is an array of line numbers containing the start item. Duplicate the file. Second pass, from one file copy to next (merge) based on hash. Third pass, delete lines based on hash.

Comment: Does order matter? If not, sort first. Then you'll have an 'xyz' line followed by another 'xyz' and you can use a regex that will merge those lines into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, I suggest first sorting the text. That will place

```
abc: ...
abc: ...
```

next to one another. Then you'll run [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/aM7vA2/1) through a few passes:

```
Search:
  ^(\w+): (.*)\n\1: 
Replace:
  \1: \2 

Result:
   abc: bla1 bla1 bla1... bla2 bla2 bla2...
   bcd: bla bla bla...
   cde: bla bla bla...
   ghk: bla1 bla1 bla1... bla2 bla2 bla2...
   lmn: bla bla bla...
   xyz: bla bla bla...
```

If order DOES matter, then [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/aM7vA2/2) can be run through a few times:

```
Search:
  ^(\w+): (.*)\n((?:(?!\1).*\n)+)\1: (.*\n)
Replace:
  \1: \2 \4\3

Result (1st pass):
  abc: bla1 bla1 bla1... bla2 bla2 bla2...
  cde: bla bla bla...
  ghk: bla1 bla1 bla1...
  lmn: bla bla bla...
  bcd: bla bla bla...
  ghk: bla2 bla2 bla2...
  xyz: bla bla bla...

Result (2nd pass):
  abc: bla1 bla1 bla1... bla2 bla2 bla2...
  cde: bla bla bla...
  ghk: bla1 bla1 bla1... bla2 bla2 bla2...
  lmn: bla bla bla...
  bcd: bla bla bla...
  xyz: bla bla bla...
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I'm looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU bash. If the order does not matter.

```
declare -A A      # declare associative array A
# fill array
while read I L; do 
  [ ${#A[$I]} -gt 0 ] && A[$I]+=" * $L"
  [ ${#A[$I]} -eq 0 ] && A[$I]+=" $L"
done < filename
# print array
for J in "${!A[@]}"; do echo "$J${A[$J]}"; done
```

Output:

```
xyz: bla bla bla...
lmn: bla bla bla...
abc: bla1 bla1 bla1... * bla2 bla2 bla2...
ghk: bla1 bla1 bla1... * bla2 bla2 bla2...
bcd: bla bla bla...
cde: bla bla bla...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk`, this should work:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]"* "$0:$0} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
ghk: bla1 bla1 bla1... * ghk: bla2 bla2 bla2...
lmn: bla bla bla...
cde: bla bla bla...
xyz: bla bla bla...
bcd: bla bla bla...
abc: bla1 bla1 bla1... * abc: bla2 bla2 bla2..
```

.